# vectors and scalars....

Tags: vectors

> If $\vec u=\hat i×(\vec a×\hat i)+\hat j×(\vec a×\hat j)+\hat k×(\vec a×\hat k)$, then:
>   (A) $\vec u$ is a unit vector
>   (B) $\vec u=\vec a+\hat i+\hat j+\hat k$
>   (C) $\vec u=2\vec a$
>   (D) $\vec u=8(\hat i+\hat j+\hat k)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Have you tried to solve the problem? I would start by evaluating/simplifying the expression for $\hat{u}$.

Comment: HI, so I evaluated the problem by applying the triple multiplication law in cross product . i arrived at $$ (\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{i})i-(\hat{i}.\hat{i})a+(\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{j})j-(\hat{j}.\hat{j})a+(\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{k})k-(\hat{k}.\hat{k})a $$

Comment: @gucci Good! Can you evaluate it further? For example, $\hat{i} \cdot \hat{i} = ??$ ... I think here we can assume that these are the base vectors of the coordinate system.

Comment: yeah I did that too I got : $$ (\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{i})i-a+(\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{j})j-a+(\overrightarrow{a}.\hat{k})k-a $$

Comment: after this step i get lost

Comment: @Matti P. u there

Comment: Next, think about what $(\vec{a}\cdot \hat{i})\hat{i}$ means, graphically. What is 
$$
(\vec{a}\cdot \hat{i})\hat{i} + (\vec{a}\cdot \hat{j})\hat{j} + (\vec{a}\cdot \hat{k})\hat{k}
$$ equal to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec u=\hat i×(\vec a×\hat i)+\hat j×(\vec a×\hat j)+\hat k×(\vec a×\hat k)$

We have $$\hat i×(\vec a×\hat i)=(\hat i . \hat i)\vec a- (\hat i. \vec a)\hat i= \vec a -(\hat i. \vec a)\hat i$$

And similarly,
$$\hat j×(\vec a×\hat j)=\vec a- (\hat j. \vec a)\hat j$$
$$\hat k ×(\vec a×\hat j)=\vec a- (\hat k. \vec a)\hat k$$

But, $(\hat i. \vec a)$ is the abscissa of $\vec a$ (i.e. the first component of the vector $\vec a$ i.e. $a_x$)

So, $(\hat i. \vec a)\hat i +(\hat j. \vec a)\hat j+ (\hat k. \vec a)\hat k=\vec {a_x}+ \vec {a_y}+ \vec {a_z} =\vec a$

Thus $$\vec u=\vec a + \vec a +\vec a -\vec a= 2\vec a$$

Comment: thanks a lot.....

Comment: Your welcome :-)