# Determining value of product $ (2\vec{a}+\vec{b}).[(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times(\vec{a}-2\vec{b})]$

Tags: vectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drBGD.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/455pq.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lo05.jpg)If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b} $ are vectors in space given by $\vec{a} = \frac{\hat{i}-2\hat{j}}{\sqrt{5}}$ and  $\vec{b} = \frac{2\hat{i}+\hat{j}+3\hat{k}}{\sqrt{14}}$ , then value of $ (2\vec{a}+\vec{b}).[(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times(\vec{a}-2\vec{b})]$ is

> (A) ${2}$
>
> (B) ${3}$
>
> (C) ${5}$
>
> (D) ${13}$
>
> Okay, so this a question from my book which I have been attempting for the last 2 hours. I solved it in the traditional way by solving each part separately and then combining them together, but still, the answer came out to be wrong. this is an MCQ question so I am guessing that there must be a way of solving this question in much less time and with more accuracy.
>   can somebody please help me out with this question.
>   Thanks
>   Regards

[image: calculations]

[image: additional_calculations]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Note: This is the second PSQ of this user so far with a title almost identical to the first [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3189539).

Comment: yeah sure, I will edit and upload the calculations i did

Comment: I didn't know what to name the title, can you please suggest one so that I can edit it

Comment: What have you got for $$\vec{a}\times \vec{b}$$?

Comment: I am just uploading the pics

Comment: I got $$5$$ for your product

Comment: i also have another page of working how do i upload that image

Comment: there you go added both the pages

Comment: anybody still here ?

Comment: Please do
[not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not
viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Do your calculation with $a$ and $b$ first and after  simplifying what you have as much as possible substitute the values of $a$ and $b$

You'll get that $(2\vec{a}+\vec{b}).[(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times(\vec{a}-2\vec{b})]=5a^2b^2 - 5(\vec a.\vec b)^2$

Also, $a^2=||\vec a||^2=1$, $b^2=1$ and $(\vec a. \vec b)=0$

So the right answer will be $(c)$ $5$

**Rules you'll use:**

$(1)$ $\vec u × (\vec a +\vec b)=\vec u × \vec a + \vec u × \vec b$

$(2)$ $(\vec u × \vec v)×\vec w=(\vec u. \vec w)\vec v - (\vec v. \vec w)\vec u$

$(3)$ $\vec a. \vec b=\vec b. \vec a$

$(4)$ $\hat i. \hat i= \hat j. \hat j=1$

$(5)$ $\hat i. \hat j=0$

$(6)$ $\vec a.\vec b=a _xb_x +a_yb_y + a_zb_z$

$(7)$ $a^2=\vec a. \vec a= ||\vec a||.||\vec a||.\cos (0)= ||\vec a||^2$

What you'll get is:

$(2\vec a +\vec b)(2b^2\vec a -(\vec a.\vec b)\vec a +a^2\vec b -2(\vec a. \vec b)\vec b)$

$= 4a^2b^2-2(\vec a.\vec b)a^2 +2a^2(\vec a.\vec b) -4(\vec a.\vec b)^2 +2b^2(\vec a.\vec b)-(\vec a.\vec b)^2+a^2b^2- 2(\vec a.\vec b)b^2$

$=5a^2b^2-5(\vec a.\vec b)^2$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92506/discussion-on-answer-by-fareed-af-determining-value-of-product-2-veca-vec).